# Correct Constructor arguments for basic timelock contract

Tags: solidity, constructor, timelock

just wondering why I can't get this constructor to pass. What am i doing wrong ?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// TeamLockTest

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/TokenTimelock.sol";

contract TimeLockTest is TokenTimelock {
    constructor() TokenTimelock(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, 1654368599){

}
```

Solidity says "Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected"

Answer (score 0):

The error is causes by TokenTimelock's first parameter. It's expecting a IERC20 parameter and you are passing an address instead. You have to convert the address to IERC20 and it should work:

For example something like this might work.

```
contract TimeLockTest is TokenTimelock {
    IERC20 constant myToken = IERC20(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4);
    address constant myWallet = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;

    constructor() TokenTimelock(myToken, myWallet, 1654368599) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! That worked.

I was wondering if there would be a way to add a function that returns the number of tokens the contract is storing ? I tried calling function from the IERC20 but it failed.

Comment: @Slimtradeywestcoast That is another question, it should be doable with IERC20, address(this) and balanceOf.